# Laravel: how to group by date and calculate number of hours

Tags: php, laravel

this is more of a logic question. I have this table design for all the attendance logs of every user

[image: attendance_logs table]

I can calculate the time differences and number of hours worked for each row.
What i need to do is to calculate the hours for each date and subtract 8 hours for each day to get the overtime hours.

```
for($i=0; $i < count($logs)-1; $i++ ){
    if($logs[$i]->status == 'out'){
        if ($i != 0) {
            $dattime1 = new Carbon($logs[$i]->log_date.' '. $logs[$i]->log_time);
            if ($logs[$i-1]->status == 'in') {
               $dattime2 = new Carbon($logs[$i-1]->log_date.' '. $logs[$i-1]->log_time);
               $diff = $dattime1->diff($dattime2);
               $hr_array[] = $diff->h;
               $min_array[] = $diff->i;
               $sec_array[] = $diff->s;
               $arr[] = $diff
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can get minutes and hours each row. I want to group the rows with the same dates and calculate the total hours worked so i can get the overtime.

Thanks

Comment: How do you differentiate users? By `emo_number`?

Comment: yes that is the unique identifier for each user

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test this out but it could give you an idea on how to solve it

```php
<?php

// for each date, keep adding difference in minutes here
// use date as array key
$workedMinutesPerDay = [
  // '2019-11-04' => minutes value
];

// keep 'in' date value here
$inDate = '';

foreach($logs as $log) {
  $date = new Carbon($log->log_date.' '. $log->log_time);

  // if 'in' value, remember the date and time and continue to next row
  // next row should be out
  if ($log->status = 'in') {
    $inDate = $date;
    continue;
  }

  // if you will always have 'in' then 'out' in order, this code is fine
  // but you should handle inconsistencies here

  // use remembered 'in' value stored in $inDate to calculate the diff in minutes
  $diffInMinutes = $date->diffInMinutes($inDate);

  // use $workedMinutesPerDay array with 'log_date' as key
  // if we don't have the entry for the day, add new one
  if (empty($workedMinutesPerDay[$log->log_date])) {
    $workedMinutesPerDay[$log->log_date] = $diffInMinutes;
  }

  // date entry was already there, add current diffInMinutes to previous value
  $workedMinutesPerDay[$log->log_date] += $diffInMinutes;
}
```

After running this, you would have array like this (hypothetical values), didn't calculate real values from the picture

```php
$workedMinutesPerDay = [
  '2019-11-04' => 100, // total minutes for the day
  '2019-11-05' => 200,
  '2019-11-08' => 300,
  '2019-11-11' => 400,
  '2019-11-12' => 500,
];
```